# Remove extra dashes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Here is my situation. I'm helping a client with their Woocommerce (WordPress) Site. I've been using jquery to hide the higher variation prices and only showing the lower price. There is the "-" that still shows and I want to remove that with jQuery. I've been trying for hours and not succeeded. Help would be appreciated.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$13.29</span>–<span class="amount">$332.25</span>

</del> <ins><span class="amount">$10.63</span>–<span class="amount">$151.84</span></ins>

</span>
<div class="product-meta-wrapper">

<h3 class="heading-title product-title"><a href="http://sproutman.com/shop/product/beginners-dozen-seeds/">Beginner’s Dozen Sprouting Seeds</a></h3>

<div class="second-rating"></div>   <span class="price"><del><span class="amount">$99.92</span>

</del> <ins><span class="amount">$87.89</span></ins>

</span>
<div class="list_add_to_cart"><a href="/product-category/organic-sprouting-seeds/recommendations-for-beginners/?add-to-cart=650" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="650" data-product_sku="SPRTSAMP" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Add to cart</a>

</div>
</div>
```

And my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var firstHighPrice = $('del span:nth-child(2)');
var secondHighPrice = $('ins span:nth-child(2)');
firstHighPrice.hide();
secondHighPrice.hide();
```

});

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Lyxsur/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this `each` function is applied to each `span` with `class` `price` and [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method to the `del` and `ins` elements and their `span` elements within. Then `empty` method is used to remove the dash (-). Finally, the previously detached elements are appended back again. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/a5Lyxsur/6/)

```
$('span.price').each(function () {
    var delSpans = $(this).find('del span').detach();

    $(this).find('del').empty();

    $(this).find('del').append(delSpans);

    var insSpans = $(this).find('ins span').detach();

    $(this).find('ins').empty();

    $(this).find('ins').append(insSpans);
});

var firstHighPrice = $('del span:nth-child(2)');
var secondHighPrice = $('ins span:nth-child(2)');
firstHighPrice.hide();
secondHighPrice.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the text before spans you are hinding is `-` that you also want to remove, then just use `previousSibling` to get text node to remove:

```
firstHighPrice.hide();
$(firstHighPrice[0].previousSibling).remove();

secondHighPrice.hide();
$(secondHighPrice[0].previousSibling).remove();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Lyxsur/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you put `<span></span>` tags around "-" like below

```
<span class="price">
    <del>
        <span class="amount">$13.29</span>
        <span>–<span>
        <span class="amount">$332.25</span>
   </del>
```

Then modify the selectors as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var firstHighPrice = $('del span:nth-child(2), del span:nth-child(3)');
    var secondHighPrice = $('ins span:nth-child(2), ins span:nth-child(3)');
    firstHighPrice.hide();
    secondHighPrice.hide();
});
```

Working sample is at http://jsfiddle.net/a5Lyxsur/4/

Comment: This is really proper way to do it if one can control HTML structure.